# How is Dowd's (2007) resampling procedure supposed to mitigate the problem of autocorrelated multiple-step-ahead forecasts?

Tags: forecasting, model-evaluation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, density-estimation

[Dowd "Validating multiple‐period density‐forecasting models" (2007)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/for.1025) considers evaluation of multiple-step-ahead density forecasts. There is a know problem of dependence between forecast errors induced by the forecast horizon $h$ being greater than one step ahead. This negatively affects tests of whether the predictive density is unconditionally correct such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test applied on probability integral transform (PIT) values of the realization w.r.t. the corresponding predicted densities.

Dowd offers a convenient solution in the form of a procedure that breaks down the dependence via a clever resampling scheme. The test of interest (e.g. the KS test) is then applied on resampled data. The only necessary modification is one of the test size, as the latter gets distorted by resampling. The modification is trivial; a distortion factor is estimated by resampling under the null hypothesis, and then it is applied to the desired nominal test size. Under the joint null hypothesis of the density forecast being unconditionally correct and PIT values being independent beyond lag $h-1$, this yields a valid test with correct size and relatively good power.

But how is Dowd's procedure supposed to work if the original sample is autocorrelated (and it definitely is for $h>1$)? How is changing the order of the observations and dropping some of them while including other multiple times (which is the essence of Dowd's resampling procedure) supposed to mitigate the fundamental problem that the original sample contains dependent observations and thus less information (due to positive autocorrelation) than its size suggests? After all, Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and other distributional tests are not sensitive to the order of the observations within a given sample. Thus I do not see how changing this order could help.

Concretely, I suspect the following part of the paper is incorrect. In the section "Demonstration that the ‘i.i.d. resample’ algorithm actually produces i.i.d. resamples" on p. 256, Dowd says

> Since each of the odd resample elements $y_1, y_3, y_5, \dots, y_{q−1}$ is based on an independent drawing from a uniform random number generator, then each of $y_1, y_3, y_5, \dots, y_{q−1}$ is independent of any
> preceding elements in the resample.

However, the fact that we are independently drawing elements from a given sample does not imply the elements themselves are independent. E.g. consider an extreme case of dependence where all of the elements in the sample are copies of a single element. Then no matter how we draw elements from the sample, they will end up being perfectly dependent. In the case of imperfect dependence, the same logic applies. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is a further attempt to figure out ["Result of a diagnostic test of a predictive model looking too good"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530643).